# Ошибка в DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Первый раз выскочило предупреждение в DevTools :

```
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map
```

Что это может быть и как решить данную проблему ? 
P.S. читал на просторах интернета, что можно скрыть это предупреждение, но это же не решение проблемы.

Comment: Написать автору расширения

Comment: Возможно ответ имеющийся тут, вам поможет - https://superuser.com/questions/1523427/google-chrome-devtools-failed-to-parse-sourcemap-chrome-extension

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь решение: [Страница на форуме с аналогичным вопросом](https://qna.habr.com/q/644551), там как решение предлагается отключить эти "source maps" в настройках браузера.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

В Chrome есть поддержка исходных карт в инструментах разработчика и соответственно он не может их найти если вас это прям так напрягает отключите